# Foreign Key Does Not Appear to Work As Intended?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm designing an airline reservation system on SQL and I got two questions:

**1.** Is this the proper way of creating a bridge table with a composite key (Where you have two primary keys and they are both foreign keys referencing other tables)?

```
CREATE TABLE FlightAndWeekday
(
WeekID int(1) NOT NULL,
FlightID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (WeekID, FlightID),
CONSTRAINT fk_FAW_WeekId FOREIGN KEY (WeekID) REFERENCES `Weekday`(`WeekID`),
CONSTRAINT fk_FAW_FlightID FOREIGN KEY (FlightID) REFERENCES `Flight`(`FlightID`)
);
```

When I run that block of code it runs successfully, but the foreign keys are not showing when I write `Show create table FlightAndWeekday`. Furthermore, I can add in records in the table that do not exist in other tables...which brings me to my next question.

**2.** Why am I able to add records in a foreign key column that do not exist in the column they are referencing? For example, I configure column A on table A to be a foreign key referencing column B on table B. However, I am able to add records in column A that do not exist in column B on table B...
The syntax that I use to create my foreign keys is:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_PaymentInfo_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
```

Comment: What storage backend are you using?   Only InnoDB enforces FK constraints, IIRC.

Comment: Hi BadZen, that was actually the problem. I was using MyISAM. After changing it to InnoDB, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Weekday
(   WeekID INT PRIMARY KEY -- one of many options
)engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE Flight
(   FlightID varchar(5) PRIMARY KEY -- one of many options
)engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE FlightAndWeekday
(   WeekID int(1) NOT NULL,
    FlightID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (WeekID, FlightID),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_FAW_WeekId (WeekID) REFERENCES `Weekday`(`WeekID`),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_FAW_FlightID (FlightID) REFERENCES `Flight`(`FlightID`)
)engine=innodb;

show create table FlightAndWeekday;
CREATE TABLE `flightandweekday` (
   `WeekID` int(1) NOT NULL,
   `FlightID` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`WeekID`,`FlightID`),
   KEY `fk_FAW_FlightID` (`FlightID`),
   CONSTRAINT `flightandweekday_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`WeekID`) REFERENCES `weekday` (`WeekID`),
   CONSTRAINT `flightandweekday_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FlightID`) REFERENCES `flight` (`FlightID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Because in the last table, the *referencing* table, you have `FlightID` as part of a composite Primary Key (and that segment is not *left-most*), the helper index is created called `fk_FAW_FlightID`.

By contrast, `WeekID` is *left-most* in the PK in *referencing* so a helper index is not needed to be created.

The above commentary is seen in this excerpt in the Manual Page entitled [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

I am sure the above will honor your wishes of FK.

Comment: Hey Drew, thanks for your comment. The main problem was not with the code or anything. It was simply the fact that I was using MyISAM instead of InnoDB. Cheers!

Comment: It wasn't a comment. It was an Answer :p .... Be well